# Updating D3 histogram as data comes in

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

SO community,

I'm making a D3 histogram as an Angular directive and I want it to be able to change/update accordingly as the data it reads in changes. In other words, I am using Angular to watch the changes in data and (hope to) redraw the histogram every time the data is changed.

This might mostly be a question about D3's updating and binding of data because the $watchCollection seems to work fine. Even though I have went through [this tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch09.html#_adding_values_and_elements) on adding elements to a d3 chart, I still cannot apply it on my histogram. I think the way the elements in my histogram are nested is really confusing me...

Context: Ideally this histogram will read from an array to which data returned from several Ajax calls will get stored in. So every time a new set of data arrive, the histogram will grow itself another bar. That's why I would love to know how to update the chart as well as the x-axis properly.

Thank you! :)

The JS fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/santina/wrtenjny/1/

Code for just the d3 part is here, largely taken from mbostock's sortable bar chart.

```
        // Aesthetic settings 
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
            width = document.getElementById('performance').clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right || 
                    940 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
            barColor = "steelblue", 
            axisColor = "whitesmoke", 
            axisLabelColor = "grey",
            yText = "# QUERIES", 
            xText = "BEACON IDs";

        // Inputs to the d3 graph 
        var data = scope[attrs.data];

        // A formatter for counts.
        var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

        // Set the scale, separate the first bar by a bar width from y-axis
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(formatCount);

        // Initialize histogram 
        var svg = d3.select(".histogram-chart")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        function drawAxis(){


            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.nqueries = +d.nqueries;
            });

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.nqueries; })]);

            // Draw x-axis 
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x-axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", "-0.71em")
                .attr("x", width )
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .style("fill", axisLabelColor)
                .text(xText);

            // Draw y-axis 
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y-axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .style("fill", axisLabelColor)
                .text(yText);

            // Change axis color 
            d3.selectAll("path").attr("fill", axisColor);
        }

        function updateAxis(){
            console.log(data);
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.nqueries = +d.nqueries;
            });

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.nqueries; })]);

            svg.selectAll("g.y_axis").call(yAxis);
            svg.selectAll("g.x_axis").call(xAxis);

        }


        function drawHistogram(){

            drawAxis();

            var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "barInfo");

            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.nqueries); })
                .attr("fill", barColor);

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("dy", "-1px")
                .attr("dx", x.rangeBand()/2 )
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "numberLabel")
                .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.nqueries); });
        }

        // Doesn't work :( 
        function updateHistogram(){
            console.log("updating");

            // Redefine scale and update axis 
            updateAxis(); 

            // Select 
            var bar = svg.selectAll(".barInfo").data(data);

            // Update - rect 
            var rects = bar.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

            // Update 
            var texts = bar.selectAll("text")
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("dx", x.rangeBand()/2 );

            // Enter 
            bar.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "bar").selectAll("rect").append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.nqueries); })
                .attr("fill", barColor);

            bar.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "bar").selectAll("text").append("text")
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
                .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
                .attr("dy", "-1px")
                .attr("dx", x.rangeBand()/2 )
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "numberLabel")
                .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.nqueries); });

        }

        drawHistogram();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you got the wrong `class` selector when you update your axis:

```
svg.selectAll("g.y-axis").call(yAxis); //<-- dash not underscore
svg.selectAll("g.x-axis").call(xAxis);
```

Second, you were close on your update, but we can clean it up a bit:

```
// select on what you originally binded data to
var bar = svg.selectAll(".barInfo").data(data);

// for data entering
var bEnter = bar.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "barInfo");    
// append a rect
bEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar");
// and the text elements
bEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class","numberLabel");

// now we can update everybody together
bar.select("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.nqueries); })
    .attr("fill", barColor);

bar.select("text")
    .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.nqueries) })
    .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.name) })
    .attr("dy", "-1px")
    .attr("dx", x.rangeBand()/2 )
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "numberLabel")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.nqueries); });
```

Udpated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrtenjny/2/).

**EDITS**

Opps, I'm not selecting correctly on my updates.

```
bar.selectAll("rect")
```

Should be:

```
bar.select("rect")
```

This fixes both the updates and the sorting...

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrtenjny/7/).

Also notice that I collapsed your code further.  With your angular watch you really don't need a seperate draw and update function, one can do both.

Comment: Thank you @Mark!! The misspelling of the class name was so dumb of me... It's also cool that you could update everything together like that! :) 
 One last thing, adding new data seems to break the sorting function, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/santina/wrtenjny/5/  Do you know why that's the case?

Comment: In your example, it looks like the graph doesn't update itself completely. After clicking on "change data", the first two bars should change too, but they don't. I'm not sure why...

Comment: @Santina, my apologies, I answered a little too quickly and screwed by my sub-selects!  See updates.

Comment: No worries at all, thank you so much for following up! :D  Lastly, would you mind briefly explain how 'selectAll' vs 'select' make such a big difference?  I'm reading [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) but I'm not sure how "selectAll" caused the behaviors we saw earlier with the sorting.

Comment: @Santina, read the documentation [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#select).  The key is the line `If the current element has associated data, this data is inherited by the returned subselection, and automatically bound to the newly selected elements.`

Comment: Got it! Thank you for helping me better understand how selection works.

Comment: For anyone else who's reading, fyi the code in my fiddle is actually not very reusable as a good angular directive. So I fixed up a few things and [this](https://gist.github.com/santina/b28d77249feec2afd370) is the final version (fully function thanks to @Mark's help).   :)